# Error with Anova function (car library) in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, anova, multivariate-testing, manova

I'm conducting a multivariate multiple regression.
As response variable, I have a function [ *y(t)* ] that I have discretized on a grid of 27 points, and 3 scalar regressors (*x1,x2,x3*).
I have replaced the response function with an nxq (q=27) matrix **Y** and what I need to solve is:

**Y = XB + E**

where **X** [nxp (p=3)] is *x1,x2,x3* column-stacked, **B** is a p×q matrix of regression coefficients and **E** is an n×q matrix of errors.
What I have done up to now is calling lm: `mylm<-lm(Y ~ X)` which regresses each dependent variable separately on the predictors.

Now I want to determine whether a predictor jointly contributes to all the 27 models I get, but I don't know how to overcome the errors I get.
When I call `Anova` this is what I get

```
Anova(mylm)

Error in eigen(qr.coef(if (repeated) qr(x$SSPE[[term]]) else SSPE.qr,  : 
  infinite or missing values in 'x'
```

and, if for example, I want to test if x2 is statistically different from 0, I get the following

```
hyp =c(0,0,1,0)
rhs =rep(0,27)
lh.out <- linearHypothesis(mylm, hyp,rhs)

Error in linearHypothesis.mlm(mylm, hyp, rhs) : 
  The error SSP matrix is apparently of deficient rank = 25 < 27
```

If the problem is related to the non-singularity of a matrix, how can I ask to use the pseudoinverse?

EDIT--------------

[Here you can find my data](https://www.jetdrop.net/FWYvt7FIp0e#JwGgTGCMIKw+AWekAcLxlBUkDMoB2AkYXESYMcgNnQWKXL3GoH0ARABwFkA5ALxS4AagCUAYjHGQAhjADmAezD9uASQDu3DQEcARgHkCAFQCmAZQAeQA)

Comment: Could you post a reproducible example?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I added a link to my datasets ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put your data in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/davidaarmstrong/469e2159d4802bae6fa09bad34527df0#file-github_data1-r), so it can be easily sourced in.  I actually get the `Anova()` function from `car` to work.  I think the difference is putting all of the data in a data frame (or tibble in this case) and then using `cbind()` to create the multivariate DV.

```
source("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/davidaarmstrong/469e2159d4802bae6fa09bad34527df0/raw/a25a02280841f4df3c6d8c10720f404586498b13/github_data1.r")

mydat <- cbind(Y, X)
mylm <- lm(cbind(V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6, V7, 
                 V8, V9, V10, V11, V12, V13, 
                 V14, V15, V16, V17, V18, V19, 
                 V20, V21, V22, V23, V24, V25) ~ 
             PC1D + PC2D + PC1H, data=mydat)
Anova(mylm)
# Type II MANOVA Tests: Pillai test statistic
#      Df test stat approx F num Df den Df    Pr(>F)    
# PC1D  1   0.20085    4.424     25    440 3.981e-11 ***
# PC2D  1   0.18632    4.030     25    440 9.065e-10 ***
# PC1H  1   0.71205   43.522     25    440 < 2.2e-16 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```